# How can I draw a graph in PHP?

Tags: php, web-applications

I have a graph which is induced by an adjacency matrix in PHP (i.e. a two dimensional array). I want to be able to draw an image of this graph, with nodes being circles, and arrows denoting edges. I also want to decorate the nodes / edges with some labels if possible.

I couldn't find any package that does that in PHP. Plenty for Matlab and other math programs.

I prefer not to use GD, because drawing graphs requires quite many calculations for doing right (deciding on edge length, distance between nodes, etc.)

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output? Browser or image file?

Comment: I want to put it in the browser window, but I don't mind if it comes as an image.

Comment: Google for "plot php" gives several nice libraries. (I haven't worked with any of them, so can't recommend.)

Comment: These are js based, I have used them on php projects before, https://developers.google.com/chart/ and http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would use javascript to display it. Check out [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for example. With that one you can [preprocess data from a database](http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database) and the charts are nice